# infinite scroll doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

it looks it doesn't work with code below, what's wrong with it? it cannot work, no error as well.

```
<h1> Infinite Scroll Demo </h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
        <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
    </div>

    <a id="next" href="demo2.html">next page</a>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>

    <script>

        $('#container').infinitescroll({
            navSelector     : "#next:last",
            nextSelector    : "#next:last",
            itemSelector    : ".includeitem"
        });

     </script>
```

Below is code for demo2.html, just some div content added to first page.

```
    <div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>
<div class="includeitem"> www.gbin1.com </div>

<a id="next" href="demo12.html">next page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wrapping element to your navigation so you aren't using the same ID for two differing items.

Also, you don't need:

```
nextSelector: #next:last
```

just use:

```
nextSelector: #next
```

It's possible it's the :last breaking it - try using Firebug/web inspector and see what $('#next:last') returns on your first page, but more than likely it's the lack of a pagination container.